# AJAX post-ing of python dictionary leads to JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, django

I am passing a python dictionary to a template then $.post-ing it to a view in django,
and when I try to json.loads it in my post view, I get JSONDecodeError.
Anyone know how I can fix this?

```
//1. vars to templates


@login_required
def bracket(request):
    '''

    :param request:
    :return:
    '''
    ...

    context = {'arr':json.dumps(tournament_games_json_serializable), 'nested':nested_tournament_games['rounds']}#{'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'madness/bracket.html', context)


//2. AJAX post of template var

$.post('{% url "update_bracket"  %}',
        { bracketData: "{{arr}}" },
        function(data, status, xhr) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
var nested = JSON.stringify(data);
        }).done(function() {  })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, ex) { alert('failed, ' + ex); });

//3.  update_bracket

@csrf_exempt
def update_bracket(request):
    bracketData = request.POST['bracketData']
    print(json.loads(bracketData))
    ...
```

where tournament_games_json_serializable is

```
tournament_games_json_serializable
{'round_1_game_1': {'players': (2, 3), 'winner': None, 'loser': None, 'done': False}, 'round_2_game_1': {'players': (1, 'winner of Round 1 Game 1'), 'winner': None, 'loser': None, 'done': False}}
```

request.POST['bracketData']

```
'{&quot;round_1_game_1&quot;: {&quot;players&quot;: [2, 3]...
```

json.loads(bracketData)

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html.unescape()`:

```
import json
import html
bracketData = '{&quot;round_1_game_1&quot;: {&quot;players&quot;: [2, 3]}}'
print(json.loads(html.unescape(bracketData)))
```

Output:

```
{'round_1_game_1': {'players': [2, 3]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter?

```
{ bracketData: "{{arr|safe}}" },
```